# Ajax post запрос не отправляется

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

кнопка и форма

```
<form id="form">

<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 test-1-fbs">Log in</button>
```

скрипт

```
function l () {
  $('#submit').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://site/api/login",
      method: "POST",
      data: $('form').serialize(),
    });
  });
}
```

пишу на vue 3

Comment: у form есть данные в формате <input name="phone" id="phone"/>

Comment: А в скрипте есть строка `l()`?

Comment: на кнопку повесил `onClick=(l();)`

Comment: ```<button type="button">```